# Quick method for finding expected value of one variable

Tags: probability, statistics

Let there be the random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, ..., $X_n$. We are given the PDF $f_{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$. Our goal is to find $\mathbb E(X_i)$.

We could first find $f_{X_i}(x_i)$, and then calculate $\mathbb E(X_i) = \int_{X_i} x \cdot f_{X_i}(x) dx$. However, finding the marginal $f_{X_i}(x_i)$ requires integrating $f_{X_1, X_2, ..., X_n}(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ a total of $n - 1$ times.

Is there a less computational expensive way get $\mathbb E(X_i)$?

Comment: In general, no.

Comment: Since you are doing this computationally, I recommend that you use MCMC to sample the space according to the full pdf, and keep running sums for each $x_i$.

Comment: Let's say we want to get $\mathbb E(X_i)$ for many different $i$. Would it make sense to store the intermediary marginals for use later - a dynamic programming solution? And could this dynamic programming solution work with MCMC, or does the misestimation risk cascade out of control?

For example, to get $f_{X_1}$ and $f_{X_2}$ from $f_{X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4}$, it would be useful to first calculate $f_{X_1, X_2}$.